# Extract div content from htmlsource in string (Java)

Tags: java, html, extract

i'm trying to extract the content of an special div-tag(defined by his classname) out of a string that contains html source. I think the regexp-features of Java are not as easy to use as in perl, right?

Does anyone did this before and can give me a piece of code? perhaps dom-browsing is a good solution, but i didn't found any tutorials, matching to my problem.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: do you only need to parse the div tag, or the whole document?

Comment: I read the whole html document ... it's a kind of crawler. the input would be something like:
 <html> ... some other code ... <div class="myDiv">text i want to extract, can contain blanks, newlines and other tags</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments it sounds like you have a general case ("crawler") and thus you're effectively parsing an XML file.  If the source page is xhtml, then you have a variety of options in various XML libraries.  (JDom, for example).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) or some other HTML parsing library from this [list](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers).